# Do I need to commit transactions in Django 1.6?

Tags: django

I want to create and object, save it to DB, then check if there is another row on the DB with the same `token` with `execution_time`=0. If there is, I want to delete the object created then restart the process.

```
transfer = Transfer(token = generateToken(size=9))
transfer.save()
while (len(Transfer.objects.filter(token=transfer.token, execution_time=0))!=1):
    transfer.delete()
    transfer = Transfer(token = generateToken(size=9))
    transfer.save()
```

Do I need to commit the transaction between every loop? For example calling `commit()` at the end of every loop?

```
while (len(Transfer.objects.filter(token=transfer.token, execution_time=0))!=1):
    transfer.delete()
    transfer = Transfer(token = generateToken(size=9))
    transfer.save()
    commit()

@transaction.commit_manually
def commit():
    transaction.commit()
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add atomic = True to your django settings. this turns every database interaction into a transaction/

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described I don't think you need to use transactions. You're basically recreating a transaction rollback manually with your code.

I think the best way to handle this would be to have a database constraint enforce the issue. Is it the case that `token` and `execution_time` should be unique together? In that case you can define the constraint in Django with [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together). If the constraint is that `token` should be unique whenever `execution_time` is `0`, some databases will let you define a constraint like that as well.

If the constraint were in the database you could just do a [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in a loop until the `Transfer` was `created`.

If you can't define the constraint in the database for whatever reason then I think your version would work. (One improvement would be to use `.count()` instead of `len`.)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create and object, save it to DB, then check if there is
>   another row on the DB with the same token with execution_time=0. If
>   there is, I want to delete the object created then restart the
>   process.

There are few ways you can approach this, depending on what your end goal is:

1. Do you want that no other record is written while you are writing yours (to prevent duplicates?) If so, you need to get a lock on your table, and to do that, you need to execute an atomic transaction, with [`@transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) (new in 1.6)
2. If you want to make sure that no duplicate records are created given a combination of fields, you need to enforce this at the database level with [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

I believe combining the above two will solve your problem; however, if you want a more brute force approach; you can override the `save()` method for your object, and then raise an appropriate exception when a record is trying to be created (or updated) that violates your constraints.

In your view, you would then catch this exception and then take the appropriate action.

Comment: Regarding 1, it is not generally true that starting a transaction will lock the table (or its equivalent). That would depend on the database, its setup, and the isolation level of the transaction. So you can't assume that running inside a transaction will prevent concurrent inserts.